# Could not able to find the Null space of a matrix , and getting empty vector as output

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, linear-algebra

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = k/(4*b^3*(1 - Cosh[b]*Cos[b]));
a1 = (Cos[b*x] - Cosh[b*x]);
a2 = (Sin[b*x] - Sinh[b*x]);
phi1 = (Cos[b] - Cosh[b])*(Sin[b*(1 - z)] - Sinh[b*(1 - z)]);
phi2 = (Sin[b] - Sinh[b])*(Cos[b*(1 - z)] - Cosh[b*(1 - z)]);
phi3 = (Sin[b] + Sinh[b])*(Sin[b*(1 - z)] - Sinh[b*(1 - z)]);
phi4 = (Cos[b] - Cosh[b])*(Cos[b*(1 - z)] - Cosh[b*(1 - z)]);
f[k1_, z1_] := 
  Module[{s1}, k = k1; z = z1; 
   s1 = (a*((phi1 - phi2)*(a1 /. x -> z) + (phi3 + phi4)*(a2 /. 
           x -> z))); s1];
p11 = 1 - f[1*^12, 0.25];
p12 = -f[1*^12, 0.25];
p21 = -f[1*^12, 0.75];
p22 = 1 - f[1*^12, 0.75];
R = {{p11, p12}, {p21, p22}};
p = FullSimplify[Det[R]]
s2 = NSolve[p == 0 && 0 < b < 30]
s3 = b /. s2;
s4 = s3[[1]];
R1 = R /. b -> s4;
NullSpace[R1]
```

I have `Matrix` which contains `Trig Function` which is having a dependency on `b` . I took the `Det` of that `Matrix` and found  `b`. I Substitute back one of the `b` in the `Matrix R` and tried to find the NullSpace of that `Matrix`, but end up in getting an empty matrix. Is there any other way to `**Find the NullSpace of a Matrix in Mathematica**`

Comment: Try lowering from default `Tolerance`: `NullSpace[R1, Tolerance -> 10^(-4)]` for example. Also could `NSolve` to higher precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I am doing here what Daniel Lichtblau suggested:
First, I rationalize the matrix `R` in order to compute with higher precision. Then -- instead of `NSolve` (which appears to have a hard time) -- I use `FindRoot` with increased precision and with initial guesses generated by the undocumented function `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` (it computes all intersection of `Line` objects within a `Graphics` object). Afterwards, the solutions for `b` have sufficiently high accuracy such that `NullSpace` with its standard setting for `Tolerance` has no problems swallowing them.

```
R = Rationalize[R];
p = FullSimplify[Det[R]];
x0 = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Plot[{p, 0}, {b, 0, 30}]][[All, 1]];
sol = FindRoot[p, {b, #}, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 40] & /@ x0;
NullSpace /@ (R /. sol)
```

> {{{-0.707106781186547524400844362, -0.707106781186547524400844362}},  {{-0.7071067811865475244008444, -0.7071067811865475244008444}},  {{-0.70710678118654752440084, -0.70710678118654752440084}},  {{-0.7071067811865475244008, -0.7071067811865475244008}},  {{-0.7071067811865475244008, -0.7071067811865475244008}},  {{-0.707106781186547524401, -0.707106781186547524401}},  {{-0.707106781186547524, -0.707106781186547524}},  {{-0.70710678118654752, -0.70710678118654752}}}

Comment: Where can I get more informationGraphics`Mesh`FindIntersections? what you are suggesting is like between 0 to 30 there are 17 roots, and it gives me null space for all 17 right?

Comment: it is working thanks for the suggestion